# Ansible can't handle kubectl proxy command

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, kubectl

I have an Ansible script that installs a Kubernetes cluster and is supposed to enable the dashboard. One task is giving me issues:

```
- name: Expose Dashboard UI
  shell: kubectl proxy --port=8001 --address={{ hostvars['master'].master_node_ip }} --accept-hosts="^*$" >> dashboard_started.txt
  args:
    chdir: $HOME
    creates: dashboard_started.txt
```

The problem is that this works, but the command `kubectl proxy` is blocking: you can't type in another command until you ctrl+c out of the command, at which point the dashboard is inaccessible. My Ansible script freezes from performing this command. I can successfully connect to the dashboard in my browser while Ansible is frozen. But I need Ansible to perform other tasks after this one as well. I have tried adding an ampersand `&` at the end of my command:

`kubectl proxy --port=8001 --address={{ hostvars['master'].master_node_ip }} --accept-hosts="^*$" >> dashboard_started.txt &`

Or

`kubectl proxy --port=8001 --address={{ hostvars['master'].master_node_ip }} --accept-hosts="^*$" & >> dashboard_started.txt`

And while both these commands cause Ansible to execute and pass over my task, I can't reach the dashboard. Using the `jobs` command on the machine the command is run on shows no background tasks, either for root or the Ansible user.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

To those reading this: **DO NOT DO THIS UNLESS YOU CAN ACCESS THE DASHBOARD FROM LOCALHOST**. If you are running Kubernetes Dashboard in a VM or on some external server, and are trying to access it from another machine (the VM host for example), you will NOT be able to log in. See here:

https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/accessing-dashboard/1.7.x-and-above.md

> NOTE: Dashboard should not be exposed publicly using kubectl proxy
>   command as it only allows HTTP connection. For domains other than
>   localhost and 127.0.0.1 it will not be possible to sign in. Nothing
>   will happen after clicking Sign in button on login page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could run the task with the asynchronous option. For example:

```
- name: Expose Dashboard UI
  shell: "(kubectl proxy --port=8001 --address={{ hostvars['master'].master_node_ip }} --accept-hosts="^*$" >> dashboard_started.txt >/dev/null 2>&1 &)"
  args:
    chdir: $HOME
    creates: dashboard_started.txt
  async: 10
  poll: 0
```

When poll is 0, Ansible will start the task and immediately move on to the next one without waiting for a result.

I personally added the subshell parentheses though i suppose that there is no need to use them, async itself does the trick I hope!

Hope it helps!

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html